# Starting 2 instances of same QT_OBJECT -> blocking each other?

Tags: qt

I want to start 2 instances of the same QT_OBJECT-class.

```
marketana_quickwfa_dialog* madid = new marketana_quickwfa_dialog(((marketana_asksettings_dialog*)QObject::sender())->config_as_json(), sysuid, mconf);
madid->show();
madid->start_quick_wfa();
```

This window has a progress bar.

**If I start 2 instances that run at the same time**, only the progress bar of the first gets updated, until the first finishes. When this happens, the progress bar of the second instance suddenly jumps to ~80%. 
(indicating that #2 got executed, but the GUI did not get updated?!)

**If I start 2 instances where the second waits (through mutex) until the first finishes**, 
suddenly the first instance does not longer execute its start_quick_wfa() code as soon as the second instance is created.
(indicating that #1 execution is blocked?! #2 is blocked anyway, as it waits for #1)

Is this a proper QT behaviour, and if so, what can I do?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WARNING: Don't use `QObject::sender()` anywhere except inside slot, and even then, with great care.

Comment: Could you show the code where you create and show the other dialog?

Comment: @RobbieE: Thanks, it is within a slot and this part works :)
This slot just gets called twice, but as soon as the 2nd dialog is spawned, the first one just does not continue to execute start_quick_wfa() [it is spawning threads and that is not longer done as soon as the 2nd starts]

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple: the `start_quick_wfa()` method blocks. And you're not showing us the minimal, self-contained, compilable example that reproduces the problem. It's not Qt's behavior, it's behavior of your own code.

Comment: This is inside a slot. Basically it is all code for this slot, so when I accept the marketana_asksettings_dialog, this is called, and it is called twice (both dialogs are showing, so that is not the problem).
But as soon as the 2nd dialog is spawned, the first one just does not continue to execute start_quick_wfa() [it is spawning threads and that is not longer done as soon as the 2nd starts]